# Make div jump down on another row if window gets smaller (with CSS Grid)

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-grid

So I have recently found out that CSS Grid is becoming more and more mature, i.e. the most browsers support it now — which is fine for my current project. I don't need IE 7 and such to be able to see this webpage in the best way possible. And I know you can probably do something clever with media queries for when the screen gets smaller,

But I was wondering if this was possible to do alone with CSS Grid for example?

So let's say I have some thing like this:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  max-width: 1200px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 25px;
}

.item-1,
item-2,
item-3 {}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-1">Some content</div>
  <div class="item-2">Some content</div>
  <div class="item-2">Some content</div>
</div>
```

So without much styling this should just result in three columns with equally large divs. My question is whether it is possible to say something like: "If when window is minimized, and a `div` inside the `.container`div get smaller that some value (like `200px`), then move the outermost right div (`.item-3`) below `item-1` and follow the same width path as `item-1` and not stretch to be as wide as both `item-1`and `item-2`".

Can this be done in a simple way, I do I actually need media queries for that?

Comment: Yes you will have to do media queries for that. Frameworks like bootstrap have those media queries built in so it seems automatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "If when the window is minimized, and a div inside the `.container` div gets smaller that some value (like 200px), then move the outermost right div (`.item-3`) below `item-1` and follow the same width path as `item-1` and not stretch to be as wide as both `item-1`and `item-2`.

How is the browser supposed to know you want to re-arrange the layout when an item becomes smaller than 200px wide?

How is the browser supposed to know what to do when the media feature is triggered?

So, yes, you'll need media queries. This is exactly what they are for.